# PHP PDO Universal check value exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a function that checks wether a given value exists in a given column of the given table in PHP using PDO to connect to a MySQL database.

First I tried this:

```
function checkExists($table, $column, $value) { 
    try {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT :column FROM :table WHERE :column2 = :value");
        $sth->bindParam(':column', $column);
        $sth->bindParam(':column', $table);
        $sth->bindParam(':column2', $column);
        $sth->bindParam(':value', $value);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchColumn() == $value;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Can\'t check exist: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

But that gave me:

`Can't check exist: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE ? = ?' at line 1`

Once I figured out that the table may not be dynamic, I created this:

```
function checkExists($table, $column, $value) {
    switch($table) {
        case "users":
        /* all other known tables */
            try {
                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT :column FROM $table WHERE :column2 = :value");
                $sth->bindParam(':column', $column);
                $sth->bindParam(':column2', $column);
                $sth->bindParam(':value', $value);
                $sth->execute();
                return $sth->fetchColumn() == $value;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Can\'t check exist: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit();
            } 
            break;
        default:
            return false; 
    }
}
```

Now I don't get errors but the result is always true. Does anybody know the solution? I'm stuck on this for a while now and it would be really useful if I could use one universal function instead of a function for each column that has to be unique(like email and username).

---

Considering the comments, I edited my code to:

```
/* Removes any unwanted input */
function cleanInput($input) {
    return stripslashes($this->removeQuotes($this->removeTags($input)));
}

/* Removes anything from < till > from the input */
function removeTags($input) {
    $regex = "/<[^<]*?>/";
    $replacement = "";
    return preg_replace($regex, $replacement, htmlspecialchars_decode($input));
}

/* Removes all ' and " from the input */
function removeQuotes($input) {
    $patterns = array(
        "'",
        '"'
    );
    $replacements = array(
        "",
        ""
    );
    return str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $input);
}

function checkExists($table, $column, $value) {
    try {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT $column FROM $table WHERE $column = :value LIMIT 1");
        $sth->bindParam(':value', $value);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchColumn() == $value;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Can\'t check exist: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}

function checkEmailExists($email) {
    return $this->checkExists("users", "email", $email);
}

function checkUsernameExists($username) {
    return $this->checkExists("users", "username", $username);
}
```

It still requires me to write a short function for each value I'd like to check but it seems there is no other/safer solution.

Comment: Not possible. placeholders cannot replace field/table names - they can  only replace VALUES. you'll have to use good-old-injection prone `WHERE $column = :value`

Comment: Hav you ever heard something of real escaping the strings you're injecting? - It would be good to escape the to avoid SQL Injection.